# Analogue of "SELECT * WHERE city != null" in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The question is, how to find data in my db, where `city != null`?

```
       userdata.find({ /*???*/ }, function (err, results) {
         if (!err) console.log(results)
         ...
       });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `$exists`. The documentation is [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/)

it should be like this

```
useedata.find({ city: { $exists: true } }, function(error, results) {
  if (!error) console.log('results' + results)
})
```

Comment: It is correct, but I have data in my collection with value "null"...

Comment: then you can use **userdata.find({ city: { $not: null } })**